What do I need to include in a Spyder 5 plugin to allow access to the active .py program in the editor plane?
I am trying to write a Spyder 5 plugin.  I have managed to create some toolbar buttons that display text boxes but I would like to extract a variable from the active program in the editor and display it in the QMessageBox.
    def setup(self):
        """Create actions and add them to the toolbar"""
        
        # Widgets
        title = _('Toolbar')
        self.toolbar = CustomToolbar(self, title)

        show_information = self.create_action(
            CustomToolbarActions.ShowWarning,
            text=_('Show Info'),
            tip=_('Show information'),
            icon=self.create_icon('MessageBoxInformation'),
            triggered=self.show_information,
        )
        self.add_item_to_toolbar(
            show_information,
            self.toolbar,
            section=CustomToolbarSections.Second,
        )

    def show_information(self):

        someText = #Get active explorer tab, get list of variables[0] # <-------- Help??
        
        QMessageBox.information(
            self,  # Parent
            _("Information"),  # Window title
            _(someText),# Message
            QMessageBox.Ok  # Buttons
        )

